# Mysql REGEXP: In my statement first comes the regex expression, then keyword REGEXP, then the "pure" value

Tags: mysql, string

Better to give an example right away:

| id | city | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Boston|Chicago | --> match if city is one of |
| 2 | [^Houston] | --> match if city is anything else but this |
| 3 | New York|Miami | --> match if city is one of |

My SQL (MySQL) statement looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE city REGEXP '" . $city . '" AND some_other_col REGEXP '" . $otherCol . '";
```

And it must stay this way, using `NOT REGEX` is not an option (as far I can tell). The idea is to keep this table as compact as possible (not caring too much if it's not really "best practice", a good pattern, etc.)

I played a bit with this checker: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-regular-expression/ and it turned out the way I'm trying to negate the #2 in my table does work when I try it (`SELECT * FROM products WHERE productLine REGEXP '[^Planes]';`).

However, in my statement, first comes the column value as regex expression and then the "pure" value: `... WHERE [^Houston] REGEX 'Houston'` so I guess that's the problem.

Is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems.

The REGEXP operator in MySQL requires that the regular expression is the right operand. The left operand is input text.

The fact that `'Boston|Chicago' REGEXP 'Boston'` would work, but not because it's running the left operand as a regular expression. It's running the right operand as the regular expression, and the pattern 'Boston' does occur as a substring of the text that is the left operand.

But this is only working by accident, because your regular expression patterns have full words in them.

The second problem is that you think `[^Houston]` is a regular expression that matches city names other than 'Houston'. That's not what the square brackets do in regular expressions. The square brackets mean, "any single character, that is one of the characters within the brackets. Square brackets with a `^` mean "any single character that is NOT one of the characters within the brackets." The pattern `[^Houston]` would match any city that has a character not in that list. It would fail to match any other city name made of those characters. Suppose there's a city named 'Toon' or 'Husnott' or 'Sooth'. Those are not 'Houston', but they are spelled using only the same characters. So the pattern '[^Houston]' finds no characters not in that list, and the regular expression fails to match.

The bottom line is that the pattern `[^Houston]` in your database is not ever going to do what you think it does.

In MySQL 8.0, the new regular expression implementation would do it:

```
<input> REGEXP '^(?!Houston).*'
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very well explained. I guess I'll have to give it up because my MySql version is low.